# Volume bounded between an Ellipsoid and a Cone?

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, volume

I'm a bit confused about how I would be able to find the volume bounded by a cone of known theta and an oblate spheroid of b = c. I'm trying to use triple integrals for the solution, and I think I understand how I can find the volume for the region bounded by a cone and a spheroid, as at any point the radius of the spheroid is constant. However, how would I be able to do that for an oblate spheroid in particular? The limits are particularly confusing me.

Comment: What equations have the oblate spheroid and cone?

Comment: the cone has theta = 5/6pi, and is translated by 15 units from the centre. the spheroid has b = 22.8, and b = 22.6, and c=b, no other transformations.

Comment: Now try setting up equations of the surfaces to find intersection lines and points and  volume integration limits.

Comment: I'm having trouble doing this in cartesian coordinates, because the projection has no points of intersection if looked at on the x-y axis. how would this be done in spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cylindrical coordinates;  due to axi-symmetry triple integrals get simpler.

Equation of oblate ellipsoid meridian

$$ (z/a)^2 + (x^2 +y^2)/b^2 =1 $$

Equation of cone

$$ (x^2+ y^2)= (z-15)^2 \tan^2\theta $$

Sketch them together and please take it further on.

Comment: Ah thank you for the help! I appreciate it!